# Add comment to Raw NBConvert cell in Jupyter

Tags: comments, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am adding the block of code mentioned [here](http://chris-said.io/2016/02/13/how-to-make-polished-jupyter-presentations-with-optional-code-visibility/) in a Raw NBConvert cell at the top of my Jupyter notebook.  I would like to both provide attribution of where the code came from and include a few notes on what the code does.

What is the syntax for adding a comment to a Raw NBConvert cell in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is problem obvious to anyone with experience in both Jupyter and HTML but the solution is to use the HTML comment syntax.

For the example linked in the question, adding a comment with the webpage for attribution would look like this in a RawNBConvert cell:

```
<script>
  <!-- 
    source:
    http://chris-said.io/2016/02/13/how-to-make-polished-jupyter-presentations-with-optional-code-visibility/
  -->
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.prompt').hide();
    $('div.back-to-top').hide();
    $('nav#menubar').hide();
    $('.breadcrumb').hide();
    $('.hidden-print').hide();
  });
</script>
```